# Using if between else in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I am trying to create 2 new variables (AGEGRP and AGEGRP2) using AGE. The AGE variable includes numerical ages that I would like to bucket into ranges.

Here is my code:

```
DATA MYTEST; 
SET test; 
if (AGE < 18) then AGEGRP = '<18';
if (18 <= AGE < 65) then AGEGRP = '>=18 to <65'; 
else if (AGE >= 65) then AGEGRP = '>=65';
if (AGE < 2) then AGEGRP2 = '<2';
if (2 <= AGE < 12) then AGEGRP2 = '>=2 to <12'; 
if (12 <= AGE < 18) then AGEGRP2 = '>=12 to <18';
else if (AGE >= 18) then AGEGRP2 = '<=18';
RUN; 
PROC PRINT DATA = MYTEST; 
RUN;
```

This yields the following:

```
AGE     AGEGRP         AGEGRP2
 5       <18             >=
 15      <18             >=
 20      >=18 to <65     >=
 1       <18             >=
 80      >=65            >=
```

I suspect there is something wrong with my between ( <= __ <  ) statements. How can I yield correct AGEGRP2 ranges?

Comment: No the issues is using if and else if incorrectly.

Comment: In the last `else if` , why is the logic condition `age >= 18` mapped to `'<=18'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issues is with the IF/ELSE IF. You haven't chained them together properly.

```
if (AGE < 18) then AGEGRP = '<18'; * Codes less than 18;

*codes 18 to 65;
if (18 <= AGE < 65) then AGEGRP = '>=18 to <65'; 

*anything else (including < 18) is recoded;
else if (AGE >= 65) then AGEGRP = '>=65';
```

This should work for you.

```
if (AGE < 18) then AGEGRP = '<18'; * Codes less than 18;

*codes 18 to 65;
else if (18 <= AGE < 65) then AGEGRP = '>=18 to <65'; 

*anything else (including < 18) is recoded;
else if (AGE >= 65) then AGEGRP = '>=65';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using your method I have AGEGRP working but not AGEGRP2. Is there something I need to add for the second set of if/else if?

Comment: Do the same thing for the second set.

Comment: @Tom I did the same thing and changed all the non first if's to else ifs but I still get all '>='s for AGEGRP2.

Comment: You cannot fit more than 2 characters into a character variable defined as length $2. Make sure to define your variables before you use them. Otherwise SAS must guess how to define them based on how they are first used. In this case by setting the value to string of length 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not include all of the `ELSE` then the last else clause overwrites the results of the earlier IF statements. IF ... THEN ...; ELSE IF ... THEN ...; ELSE ... ;

Make sure to define your variables before using them. Otherwise SAS will guess how to define them based on how they are first used. In your example AGEGRP will be length $3 and AGEGRP2 will be length $2.

Add this line before starting your IF cascades.

```
length AGEGRP AGEGRP2 $11;
```